# Python MongoEngine Audit table child class

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I'm using Mongonegine on a Flask API and i have a table with audit(2 columns with create_date and update_date).

Currently the model looks like this:

```
class ProductModel(db.Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'product', 'queryset_class': CustomQuerySet}
    id = db.SequenceField(primary_key=True)
    url = db.StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    name = db.StringField(required=True, default=generate_random_string())
    user_id = db.ReferenceField(UserModel, required=True)
    create_date = db.DateTimeField()
    update_date = db.DateTimeField()
    vendor_id = db.ReferenceField(VendorModel, required=True)
    active = db.IntField(required=True, default=1)
    subscribed_list= db.EmbeddedDocumentListField(SubscribedListDocument)
    price_history = db.EmbeddedDocumentListField(PriceHistoryDocument)
    def to_json(self):
        data = self.to_mongo()
        data["vendor_id"] = {"name" :self.vendor_id.name, "active": self.vendor_id.active}
        data["user_id"] = {"name": self.user_id.name}
        return json_util.dumps(data)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.create_date:
            self.create_date = get_current_date()
        self.update_date = get_current_date()
        return super(ProductModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I implemented the audit part in the "**save**" method.

I plan to implement the audit on another tables as well and i want to achieve that with another inherited class, something like this so i don't duplicate the save method in every model:

```
class AuditModel(Document):
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}
    create_date = DateTimeField(default=get_current_date)
    update_date = DateTimeField(default=get_current_date)
    # def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     if not self.create_date:
    #         self.create_date = get_current_date()
    #     self.update_date = get_current_date()
    #     print(self.create_date)
    #     return super(self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class ProductModel(db.Document, AuditModel):
......
```

But it's not working.

Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it thanks to this:

https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/574

Now the code looks like this:

```
class AuditModel(Document):
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True, 'abstract': True}
    create_date = DateTimeField(default=get_current_date)
    update_date = DateTimeField(default=get_current_date)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.create_date:
            self.create_date = get_current_date()
        self.update_date = get_current_date()
        return super(AuditModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class ProductModel(AuditModel):
    meta = {'collection': 'product', 'queryset_class': CustomQuerySet}
    id = db.SequenceField(primary_key=True)
    url = db.StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    name = db.StringField(required=True, default=generate_random_string())
    user_id = db.ReferenceField(UserModel, required=True)
    create_date = db.DateTimeField()
    update_date = db.DateTimeField()
    vendor_id = db.ReferenceField(VendorModel, required=True)
    active = db.IntField(required=True, default=1)
    subscribed_list= db.EmbeddedDocumentListField(SubscribedListDocument)
    price_history = db.EmbeddedDocumentListField(PriceHistoryDocument)
    def to_json(self):
        data = self.to_mongo()
        data["vendor_id"] = {"name" :self.vendor_id.name, "active": self.vendor_id.active}
        data["user_id"] = {"name": self.user_id.name}
        return json_util.dumps(data)
```

I need to add {'abstract': True} on the child class.